# HASHTABLE JAVA - ENUMERATOR VARIABLE MANEJO

Tags: java

Tengo este problema y basicamente no logro interpretar correctamente la documentación.
Estoy implementando un hashtable con el que recibo una cantidad de `cajas_tipo` para responder con medicamentos `ht(medic, cant)`.
El problema es que no logro darme cuenta como usar el *enumerator*.
Si quiero usar un put de cantidades de medicamentos, no me doy cuenta como se maneja.
Acá copio el codigo que funciona pero no responde nada.
el tema es que no encuentro documentacion con un ejemplo claro (o por lo menos no me doy cuenta) como manejar el *enumerat*, y como manejar el `var`, `Integer`
Si me indican o documentacion o una referencia.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Ejecutora {
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Administradora ad = new Administradora();
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    s.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    int opc = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("1 AGREGA un medicamento");
        System.out.println("2 AGREGA STOCK");
        System.out.println("3 MUESTRA DATOS CARGADOS");
        System.out.println("4 AGREGA UNA CAJA TIPO");
        System.out.println("0 PARA SALIR");
        opc = s.nextInt();
        switch (opc) {
        case 1:
            ad.agregaUnMedicamento();
            break;
        
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Ingrese el identificador del medicamento");
            int idm = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el codigo de la caja tipo");
            int cct = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de remedios");
            int cant = s.nextInt();
            ad.agregaMedicamentoALaCajaTipo(idm, cct, cant);
            break;
        
        case 3:
            ad.muestraDatosCargados();
            break;
        
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Ingree el codigo de la caja tipo");
            cct = s.nextInt();
            ad.agregaCaja_Tipo(cct);
            }
            } while (opc != 0);
    }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Administradora{
private ArrayList <Medicamento> medicamentos;
private ArrayList <Caja_Tipo> cajas_tipo;

public Administradora() {
    medicamentos = new ArrayList<Medicamento>();
    cajas_tipo = new ArrayList<Caja_Tipo>();
}


public void muestraDatosCargados() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese el codigo de la caja tipo");
    int cct = s.nextInt();
    Caja_Tipo ct = this.buscaCaja_Tipo(cct);
    if (ct != null) {
        ct.muestraElementos();
    }
}

public void agregaCaja_Tipo(int cct) {
    Caja_Tipo ct = new Caja_Tipo(cct);
    cajas_tipo.add(ct);
}


public void agregaMedicamentoALaCajaTipo(int idm, int cct, int cant) {
    Medicamento me = this.buscaMedicamento(idm);
    if (me != null) {
        Caja_Tipo ct = this.buscaCaja_Tipo(cct);
        if (ct != null) {
            ct.ponerMedicamentosEnLaCaja(me, cant);
        }
    }
}

public Medicamento buscaMedicamento (int a) {
    int b = 0;
    while (b < medicamentos.size() && !(medicamentos.get(b).sosMedicamento(a))) {
        b++;
    }
    if (b < medicamentos.size()) {
        return medicamentos.get(b);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

public Caja_Tipo buscaCaja_Tipo (int a) {
    int b = 0;
    while (b < cajas_tipo.size() && !(cajas_tipo.get(b).sosCaja_Tipo(a))) {
        b++;
    }
    if (b < cajas_tipo.size()) {
        return cajas_tipo.get(b);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void agregaUnMedicamento() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero identificador del medicamento");
    int idm = s.nextInt();
    Medicamento me = this.buscaMedicamento(idm);
    Medicamento nuevo = null;
    if ( me == null) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el stock del medicamento");
        int stk = s.nextInt();
        int opc = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Ingrese 1 - VACUNA | 2 - PASTILLA");
            opc = s.nextInt();
        } while (opc != 1 && opc != 2);
        if (opc == 1) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el precio de la vacuna");
            float pre = s.nextFloat();
            nuevo = new Vacuna (idm, stk, pre);
        }
        else {
            nuevo = new Pastilla (idm, stk);
        }
        medicamentos.add(nuevo);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Este medicamento ya fue cargado");
    }

    }

}



public abstract class Medicamento {
private int ID_Medicamento;
private int stock_Medicamento;

public Medicamento(int idM, int stM) {
    ID_Medicamento = idM;
    stock_Medicamento = stM;
}

public abstract float getPrecio();

public boolean sosMedicamento (int a) {
    return ID_Medicamento == a;
}

public int getID_Medicamento() {
    return ID_Medicamento;
}

public int getStockMedicamento() {
    return stock_Medicamento;
}
}



public class Pastilla extends Medicamento {

public Pastilla (int idM, int stM) {
    super (idM, stM);
}

public float getPrecio() {
    return 0;
}


}





public class Vacuna extends Medicamento {
private float precio;

public Vacuna (int idM, int stM, float pre) {
    super (idM, stM);
    precio = pre;
}

public void setPrecio(float p) {
    precio = p;
}

public float getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}
}



import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Caja_Tipo {
private int codigo_Caja_Tipo;
private Hashtable<Medicamento, Integer> medicamentos;

public Caja_Tipo(int cct) {
    codigo_Caja_Tipo = cct;
    medicamentos = new Hashtable<Medicamento, Integer>();
}

public void ponerMedicamentosEnLaCaja(Medicamento me, int cant) {
    if (medicamentos.containsKey(me))
        cant = cant + medicamentos.get(me);
    medicamentos.put(me, cant);
}

public void muestraElementos() {
    Enumeration<Medicamento> ee = medicamentos.keys();
    Medicamento medi;
    while (ee.hasMoreElements()) {
        medi = ee.nextElement();
        System.out.println("El precio del medicamento es: " + medi.getPrecio()
                            + "El stock del medicamento es: " + medi.getStockMedicamento()
                            + "El id del medicamento es: " + medi.getID_Medicamento());
    }
}

public boolean sosCaja_Tipo(int a) {
    return codigo_Caja_Tipo == a;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto a lo del `hashtable` no entiendo bien que nesecitas, ya que probe el codigo y me funciono bien, lo unico que comente fue la linea:

```
s.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Ahora, en cuanto al flujo del programa, primero debes de agregar medicamentos y tipos de cajas, para luego agregar en el stock los identificadores de los medicamentos con los tipos de cajas, y al final mostrar los datos.

En realidad el menu deberia ser de esta forma para que se entienda mejor:

```
    System.out.println("1 AGREGA UN MEDICAMENTO");
    System.out.println("2 AGREGA UNA CAJA TIPO");
    System.out.println("3 AGREGA STOCK");
    System.out.println("4 MUESTRA DATOS CARGADOS");
    System.out.println("0 PARA SALIR");
```

Recuerda que para agregar al stock debes de tener anotado (apuntado o recordar) el identificador del medicamento y el identificador de la caja. Y para mostrar los resultados debes de ingresar el tipo de caja.

Comment: Si, funciona.  No muestra ningun resultado.Creo que me voy dando una idea de como funciona eesto...

Comment: Exacto, el codigo funciona, solo debes de entender el flujo del programa y veras que te mostrara los datos.